# How do I enter new contact from "New Case" form using a contact subtype?

Tags: civicase

When I click in the Client field, I can start typing the name of an existing contact or I can click on "New Individual," "New Organization," or "New Household."

However, it doesn't list our "Hotline Caller" Individual sub-type, which is the only option I would like to have listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Go to **Administer -> Customize Data & Screens -> Profiles**
2. Click to the "Reserved Profiles" tab
3. Find the "New Individual" profile and click "Fields" then "Add Field"
4. Field type "Contact" field name "Contact SubType"
5. Save the field with whatever label, help text, etc. you wish.

You will then be able to specify the contact sub-type on any New Individual popup form.

Note: I just tested this and the resulting field uses a rather ugly multiselect widget. I've just [posted a fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6195) for this which will get into the next release.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. Ideally I wanted to control the options presented from the Client field (New Individual, New Organization, New Household), however, this work-around seems perfectly fine. And thanks for tweaking the design of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

Re-reading your question, it sounds like you want this process to be more automated. You'd like *all* case clients to become "Hotline caller" contacts. May I suggest you write a little custom code to accomplish this? If you implement [hook_civicrm_post](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_post) and then use the api to add that contact type to the client whenever a case is saved, then you won't run the risk of your users forgetting to do it manually.